# Pass "enter" from text box to another text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create 2 simple textbox in aspx file and .cs, whenever I click a button, it will pass the value to another textbox. as simple as this:

```
private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
textbox1.text=textbox2.text; 
}
```

However, the "enter" message doesn't pass to another textbox. please view the example below [image: example]

do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post more code? Have you debugged anything?

Comment: yup, i just want to pass the exact message from first textbox to another textbox. In the result I post, the "enter" value didn't pass to the second textbox

Comment: Are you trying to switch messages between the two text boxes?

Comment: Well it's really strange what you're getting there, as the output is a different string than the input. It's not only the lack of line break. The second string has a capital 'T' instead of a lower case 't'... Have you debugged the code?

Comment: Wonder why all the anonymous downVotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to do that in the button's click event, say you have a button called transfer, then create a click event called

```
private void Transfer_OnClick(......)
{
    textbox1.text=textbox2.text; 
}
```

That should be all you need, this is assuming you are using ASP.NET Webforms.

Comment: I've made the code and the button click event, but the <br> didn't pass to another text box. so if you look at the image, the input and result is different even though the text is same

Comment: Can you post the text that you get from the first textbox? exactly as it is.